# How to convert this GMT to MDT?

Tags: python, gmt

I have some GMT times I need to convert to MDT, but the format is a bit odd compared to examples i've seen here and on other pages;

What is the "+00:00" on the end of these times?  and how do I add formatting for it in my *strptime* statement?

examples:

```
2014-03-11T15:57:35+00:00
2014-03-12T22:54:16+00:00
2014-03-11T15:18:20+00:00
```

my current code:

```
t = datetime.strptime(str(answer[0][0].extendedField[item].value[0][0]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 79, in <module>
    query_scr(scr)
  File "./myscript.py", line 56, in query_scr
    t = datetime.strptime(str(answer[0][0].extendedField[item].value[0][0]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00
```

Comment: I recommend you to provide a better title.

Comment: Timezone offsets. GMT is UTC + 0 hours and 0 minutes.

Comment: Though not exactly a duplicate, I think the answer you're looking for resides here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045168/3058609 strptime cannot parse ISO formats.

Comment: What you have is the ISO date format

Comment: @AdamSmith: Correction: `strptime` cannot parse ISO formats *with timezone information*.

Comment: @AdamSmith True, but if it's absolutely known to be GMT, you can add those to the format string to have `strptime` ignore them