# Add time zone offset (in ISO 8601 format) to naive datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I need to convert a series of naive datetimes to their local tz.  Local tz is stored separately as ISO8601 format (e.g. '-0800' for PST).

I've tried replacing the datetime with a new one, adding the offset:

```
>>>utc_time 
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 24, 0, 32, 30, 998654)
>>>tz_offset
u'-0800'
>>>local_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=tz_offset)
*** TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'unicode'
```

and tried using pytz to localize(), which requires calling timezone() first:

```
>>>timezone(tz_offset)
*** UnknownTimeZoneError: '-0800'
```

*doc for this step here:http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic

Any suggestions for making these offsets work?

*similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994594/how-to-add-timezone-into-a-naive-datetime-instance-in-python) but uses a different format, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The same timezone may have different utc offsets on different dates. Use timezone names instead of a string utc offset:

```
import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

utc_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 24, 0, 32, 30, 998654)
utc_dt = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) # make it timezone aware
pc_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')) # convert to PST

print(pc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z%z'))
# -> 2014-01-23 16:32:30.998654 PST-0800
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, you need a `tzinfo` subclass (i.e. [tzinfo object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=tzinfo#tzinfo-objects)), which `pytz.timezone` returns from a timezone string, but it does not understand the offset format you are providing.

[Another relevant thread to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692869/user-specified-date-time), which links to this [google app engine application](http://timezones.appspot.com/), which also provide some source code.  Here is a quick and naive example, if you desire.

```
class NaiveTZInfo(datetime.tzinfo):

    def __init__(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=self.hours)

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return '+%02d' % self.hours
```

To handle your offset format, you have to write your own parsing logic for the format you are providing.

```
>>> t = NaiveTZInfo(-5)
>>> u = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 24, 0, 32, 30, 998654)
>>> v = u.replace(tzinfo=t)
>>> str(v)
'2014-01-24 00:32:30.998654-05:00'
```